# Can't access fields in Sugar view controller

Tags: javascript, controller, sugarcrm

I'm having a problem accessing field values in a view controller. A controller for the Resources record view takes a value from a dropdown and sets the value of a field depending on the dropdown selection. It looks like this:

```
// custom/modules/Resources/clients/base/views/record/record.js

({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this._super('initialize', [options]);
        this.model.once("sync", this.assignOnChangeFunctions, this);
    },

    assignOnChangeFunctions: function () {
        this.model.on('change:custom_rate', this.custom_rate_changed, this);
    },

    custom_rate_changed: function(){
        console.log('project_manager_l2_rate_c: ' + this.model.get('project_manager_l2_rate_c'));
        console.log('project_manager_l3_rate_c: ' + this.model.get('project_manager_l3_rate_c'));
        switch(this.model.get('custom_rate')){
            case 'Project Manager L2':
                this.model.set('resource_rate_actual',this.model.get('project_manager_l2_rate_c'));
                break;
            case 'Project Manager L3':
                this.model.set('resource_rate_actual',this.model.get('project_manager_l3_rate_c'));
                break;
        }
    },
})
```

Controller for the create view looks just like the above, except it extends from `CreateView` and instead of `this.model.once("sync", this.assignOnChangeFunctions, this)` I have `this.assignOnChangeFunctions`. The create controller works as expected. But the record controller can't access the values of `project_manager_l2_rate_c` and `project_manager_l3_rate_c` fields. The output from console.log statements is "undefined". But, I can see the values of these fields in the database. When I try to access other fields in this `Resources` record, the results are mixed. Some of the fields can be accessed and others cannot. I don't see any pattern for which fields can be accessed. It seems to make no difference whether a field is in `resources` or `resources_cstm` table. Replacing `this.model.once("sync", this.assignOnChangeFunctions, this)` with `this.assignOnChangeFunctions` makes no difference. What else can I try to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Sounds to me like those two fields are empty in Create View. Where do they get filled/initialized? On server on save with some default value? then they would still be empty in the Create View. 
A field that cannot be "accessed" is generally speaking either not loaded for an existing record (because not part of current viewdefs, i.e. record.php) or because it's still empty and hasn't been assigned any value yet.

Comment: Thank you @Jay. The field not being part of viewdefs was the problem. The field existed in the resources_cstm table, and had a value, but it was not added to the view. I am able to access the values in the controller after adding the field to the view. That's something new I learned about Sugar. You should add this as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the fields you want to use are in the layout/viewdefs in question (typically `record.php` for RecordView and CreateView).
Otherwise the field contents won't be transmitted by the server/rest-API in order to safe bandwidth and resources.